# Parse String from XML

Tags: xml

**Additional things**

**responseBody for parseXMLRecord method**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xmldata xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" status="SUCCESS">
  <recordset name="res" nritems="2">
    <record name="order" id="777">
      <field name="restorant">Black</field>
      <field name="location">West 44</field>
      <field name="ordercount">10</field>
    </record>
    <record name="order" id="888">
      <field name="restorant">Green</field>
      <field name="location">East 55</field>
      <field name="ordercount">20</field>
    </record>
    <record name="order" id="999">
      <field name="restorant">Yellow</field>
      <field name="location">East 99</field>
      <field name="ordercount">40</field>
    </record>
  </recordset>
</xmldata>
```

**parseXMLRecord method**

```
public static Map<String, XMLRecord> parseXMLRecord(String responseBody) {
    DOM.Document document = new DOM.Document();
    document.load(responseBody);

    Map<String, XMLRecord> recordMap = new Map<String, XMLRecord>();
//            Map<String, Map <String, String>> finalRecordMap = new Map<String, Map <String, String>>{};

    for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNode : document.getRootElement()
            .getChildElement('recordset', null)
            .getChildElements()) {

        String recordId = xmlNode.getAttribute('id', null);
        XMLRecord xmlRec = new XMLRecord();

        for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNodeInternal : xmlNode.getChildElements()) {
            String name = xmlNodeInternal.getAttribute('name', null);
            String value = xmlNodeInternal.getText();
            System.debug(name + ' ' + value);
            if (name == 'name') {
                xmlRec.name = value;
            }
            if (name == 'value') {
                xmlRec.value = value;
            }
        }
        recordMap.put(recordId, xmlRec);
    }

    for (String key : recordMap.keySet()) {
        System.debug('*****************');
        System.debug('key ' + key);
        System.debug('value ' + recordMap.get(key));
        System.debug('value String ' + String.valueOf(recordMap.get(key)));
        System.debug('*****************');
    }


    return recordMap;
}

class XMLRecord {
    String location;
    String restorant;
}
```

I have it in Map<String, XMLRecord> recordMap = new Map<String, XMLRecord>();

In String - I have ID

In XMLRecord - I have this line [name=first, value=?]

In the end, I want to assign this value to the custom field in SalesForce. For example from this line [name=first, value=?] i want to have

```
Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name = nameValue;   //first
        acc.value = valueValue; //?
insert acc;
```

Also i need get value for mapping from block xml where order count 20

Comment: Deleting and re-posting questions without addressing the issues in your previous question is not going to make people feel like helping you. You'll tend to attract even more downvotes. If you continue to do this enough, the system itself will bar you from asking further questions.

Comment: As I mentioned in [your previous attempt](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/369430/parse-string-from-inner-class-object), it's not clear how you're getting this data, or even if any "parsing" is required at all. You need to provide us with enough details to understand what you're working with (doubly so if you're not using the correct terminology). Show us the XML you're working with, show us how `recordMap` is being populated. It's possible to include too much code/detail, but that's a lot harder than not providing enough detail.

Comment: @DerekF updated

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the big mistake in the XML parsing you're doing right now is in trying to extract data from the `<field>` tags, the innermost loop. As it stands, your map can only hold a single "field" per order.

The point of parsing/deserializing data is to make the data easy to use in Apex. You should focus on that alone at first. After you have the data in a workable state, then you can work on arranging data into collections.

#### So, as far as changes I would make...

Your `XmlRecord` class should contain variables to hold the id, restorant (misspelling of restaurant?), location, and orderCount. Yeah, they're on separate levels of the given XML structure, but it's not a stretch to treat them as a single, logical object.

Having

```
public class XmlRecord{
    public String id;
    public String restorant;
    public String location;
    public Integer orderCount;
}
```

is easier/more robust than the alternative

```
// This is purely for illustration purposes
// You should not be using this class structure
public class XmlRecord{
    public String id;
    public List<XmlField> fields;
}
public class XmlField{
    public String name;
    public String value;
}
```

`myXmlRec.orderCount` vs `myXmlRec.fields[2]`

The changes you'd need to make to your XML parsing would be pretty minimal

```
XMLRecord xmlRec = new XMLRecord();

xmlRec.id = xmlNode.getAttribute('id', null);;

for (Dom.XmlNode xmlNodeInternal : xmlNode.getChildElements()) {
    // The result of getting the 'name' attribute will be the value of that
    //   attribute.
    // e.g. restorant, location, ordercount
    String name = xmlNodeInternal.getAttribute('name', null);

    // The text node for the field tag gets you values like 'green', 'east 55', and '20'
    String value = xmlNodeInternal.getText();

    // We don't have .put() on apex classes like we do on SObjects, so that means
    //   we pretty much need a long chain of if/else to populate data on XmlRecord
    //   (a switch can reduce some typing)
    switch on name.toLowerCase() {
        when 'restorant'{ xmlRec.restorant = value; }
        when 'location'{ xmlRec.location = value; }
        when 'ordercount'{ xmlRec.orderCount = Integer.valueOf(value); }
        when else {}
    }
}
```

Now that the data is in place, it'd be easy to add things to other maps.
A `Map<String, XmlRecord>`, keyed on the order Id seems reasonable, and the changes required are also minimal.
Your final line of the innermost loop would change from `recordMap.put(recordId, xmlRec);` to `recordMap.put(xmlRec.Id, xmlRec);`

If you want to track things by order count, a `Map<Integer, List<XmlRecord>>` would be appropriate. I can't say for sure if you could have more than one order with a given order count, so it's better to be safe and store a List rather than a single instance.

#### Now, how do you get that information into an SObject?

This is kind of a trick question. If you have more than one `XmlRecord`, you probably *don't* want to try to mash multiple pieces of data into single fields (and having multiple fields like `restorant1__c`, `restorant2__c`, etc... is poor practice). Instead, you probably want to iterate over your XmlRecords and create one SObject each.

Grabbing the data from the XmlRecord then becomes the same as accessing data from any other object (just use dot notation).

e.g.

```
List<Opportunity> oppList = new List<Opportunity>();
for(XmlRecord rec :recordMap.values()){
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
        Order_Id__c = rec.id,
        Restaurant__c = rec.restorant,
        Location_Name__c = rec.location,
        Number_Of_Orders__c = rec.orderCount
    );

    oppList.add(opp);
}
```